# Logical sum in fortran

Tags: fortran, logical-operators

In fortran I have two arrays

```
u = (/ .true. , .false. , .true. , .false. /)
v = (/ .true. , .true. , .false. , .false. /)
```

and I want to add them like

```
w = u .or. v
```

to get

```
w == (/ .true. , .true. , .true. , .false. /)
```

but the `.or.` operator does not accept arrays as input.
What's the best way to do that? I feel like I should make use of the `where` intrinsic but I am not quite sure how.

Comment: `.or.` should operate on arrays.  How does your compiler complain when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example to show that `operator(.OR.)` is in fact elemental:

```
program orme
   implicit none
   logical u(4), v(4), w(4)
   integer i
   u = [.TRUE., .FALSE., .TRUE., .FALSE.]
   v = [.TRUE., .TRUE., .FALSE., .FALSE.]
   w = u .OR. v
   write(*,'(*(g0))') 'w =',(merge(' [',', ',i==1), &
      trim(merge('.TRUE. ','.FALSE.',w(i))),i=1,size(w)),']'
end program orme
```

Output with ifort:

```
w = [.TRUE., .TRUE., .TRUE., .FALSE.]
```

**EDIT**: I see your reason for confusion: `gfortran` documents the intrinsic extension `OR(I,J)` which only works for scalars. `ifort` also documents `OR(I,J)` but it is elemental in that compiler. In both instances when it works the result is a bitwise logical `OR` of its inputs. Replace with `IOR(I,J)` to get the standard elemental version on any compiler. Also there is the logical array reduction function `ANY` and the integer array reduction function `IANY` which can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I was looking at the documentation of `or` (which wants two scalars) instead of `.or.`

Comment: DO NOT USE OR (nor IOR) on LOGICALS!!!! Yes, ifort does document OR as an alternate spelling of IOR. IOR/OR operate on integers. Yes, ifort allows, as an extension, conversion between LOGICAL and numeric types, but this leads to non-portable code that can produce unexpected results. I wrote on this general topic in 2000 - see https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/275071#comment-1548435  You should also become familiar with the ANY and ALL intrinsics - ALL is the "sum" mentioned in the title, though not what was requested.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @SteveLionel. I don't know how I missed that in the ifort docs. But logical sum is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano%E2%80%93Russell_notation) to be [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) which seems to be what `operator(.OR.)` or the `ANY(MASK)` intrinsic does. `ALL(MASK)` is logical product.